# Is there a way to access functions (VB) in a class without making an instance of the object?

Tags: vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have three classes, CarAdd, Car and EntityObject. CarAdd calls methods in EntityObject, but it doesn't have immediate access to them. Instead, it creates an object of type Car and uses it to call the methods. The problem, is that EntityObject cannot be instantiated, so is there a way for the Car class to call EntityObject's methods without an object?

I have tried to include the 'shared' functionality to the method header, but since the function implements something, I am unable to do this successfully.

```
'This executes when a button is pressed on the UI. _mCar is an object of type 'Car
'In class CarAdd
Public Sub BeginEdit()
        If _mCar IsNot Nothing Then _mCar.BeginEdit()
    End Sub

'This is the code I added to try and make this work. Since EO is nothing, 'though, the if statement never executes.
'In class Car
Private EO As EntityObject
Public Sub BeginEdit()
        If EO IsNot Nothing Then
            Call EO.BeginEdit()
        End If
    End Sub

'This is the method that I want to execute
'In class EntityObject
Public Sub BeginEdit() Implements System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject.BeginEdit
        If Not _blnIsEditing Then
            _blnIsEditing = True
            _OriginalObject = TryCast(Me.MemberwiseClone(), EntityObject)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I had hoped that the method call would, essentially, flow through the Car class and to the EntityObject class, but this isn't what's happening. Instead, the if statement in the Car class never executes, so the method is never called.

Comment: Not in your case, it's not shared (BeginEdit)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not if the `Sub`/`Function` isn't `Shared` (`BeginEdit` is not `Shared` in `EntityObject`). By definition, a non-`Shared` `Sub` or `Function` is instance-specific and can only be used via an instance.

More about shared/non-shared class members [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/index).